# how to stop broadcast service in linux

Tags: linux

I have a query: in our environment all Linux servers have broadcasting enabled

I need to stop the broadcast service in my Linux server.

I have tried to stop the service by doing the following:

1. change the broadcast address `0.0.0.0` manually
2. add the broadcast address `0.0.0.0` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

But, still same result. Can any body tell me the procedure to close the broadcast service in Linux.

Comment: What is the service that you are trying to stop broadcasting?  The steps you are taking alter the configuration of the network, and with IP a broadcast address is always defined.

Comment: Dear Pual, when i define the ip address for example ip=132.140.150.10 and netmask is =255.255.224.0 and if i check ifconfig eth0 is show that ip adress= 132.140.150.10 netmask= 255.255.224.0 Bcast=132.140.151.9 our network team told me broadcasting is enable on the linux servers you need to stop it

Comment: You need more information.  The notion of an IP address on a subnet without a broadcast address doesn't make sense.  They are probably talking about a specific service broadcasting, such as zeroconf.  Have them tell you the service or port that they are seeing the broadcast traffic appearing on and we can help you close it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do what you are trying to do.  What exactly is the problem you are seeing, and why is it a problem ?

Broadcasting is not a service, its part of the IP stack, so there isn't a way of stopping the service.  You might be able to write an IPTables rule to fix whatever it is you are trying to fix, but there will almost certainly be colateral damage, probably killing your ability to network at all.

If you don't want computers on the same network to see each other, maybe you need to assign each computer with an IP address which has a network comprising only itself and the router.  This won't stop any kind of attacks across the LAN, but might cut down on the traffic you are worried about.

Some examples (assuming 192.168.0.x subnet)
ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.252 gateway 192.168.0.2
(This will use 192.168.0.0 as the network, 192.168.0.3 as the broadcast, so you will only be able to see the router, assuming you bring up an interface on the router of 192.168.0.2 with an otherwise similar command)

```
You would then need to use
192.168.0.5  and 192.168.0.6
192.168.0.9  and 192.168.0.10
192.168.0.13 and 192.168.0.14
.
.
.
```

1 for each host with a corresponding interface/virtual interface on the core router.

Not sure what this is achieving though.

Comment: when i define the ip address for example ip=132.140.150.10 and netmask is =255.255.224.0 and if i check ifconfig eth0 is show that ip adress= 132.140.150.10 netmask= 255.255.224.0 Bcast=132.140.151.9 our network team told me broadcasting is enable on the linux servers you need to stop.

Comment: another question i would like to ask you if ip address is =132.140.150.10 and Bcast is =132.140.151.9 its send the packet to all the host in the range for example =132.140.150.9 to 50 or is not send the request earlier you said that its part of ipstack

Comment: You should ask them what traffic its broadcasting - there is probably a miscommunication between your and their meaning of the word broadcasting.

Comment: 132.140.151.9 is not a valid broadcast address (it would probably be 132.140.151.255), but assuming it was, yes, that data will be sent to all computers on the LAN IF YOU SEND A PACKET.   If you provide the first 2 lines of "ifconfig DEVNAME", I can confirm what your broadcast address is - and if you are trying to send traffic to that IP address you need to find out what is sending the traffic and stop it.  Your network guys can probably help as well by telling you the source and destination port of the traffic.